# Code inside of a python file deleted

Tags: python, restore

The code inside of a python file randomly deleted, is there anyway to restore? It is a file of 3.70 KB but when opened and put into a text document there is nothing.

Comment: Invent a timetravel travel back and copy it before it gets deleed

Comment: Reload from your most recent backup.

Comment: Gotta Git'em all !!

I don't think you'd be able to recover this. A good lesson learnt here would be to use a VCS from the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Open with python to see what it contains

```
with open('deleted.py', 'rb') as f:
   print(repr(f.read()))
```

Comment: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00   is what it contains

Comment: There is no data to extract from 3.7 kb of null bytes, sorry, say goodbye to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a new user I am assuming you are new to code development etc. Therefore, you should look at some versioning control tools like:

1. SVN
2. Github
3. Gitlab

There are some more, but these are the most common ones. They are used to store your code and to revert you code if you mess up. They are also used to merge codes when different programmers are changing it. For the moment this will not help but will help in the future.

For now you may look at some restore tools but I highly doubt it that you are able to recreate the file. Another possiblity is: when you haven IDE to look at your command history. Maybe you executed the script and you can find the executed script as commands in the command history.